# How can I pass class entity as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to pass class entity to another class have a method this is in second class

```
 public void AutoComplet(TextEdit text_searche, Class entity here)
 {
     AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

     ArrayList fo = new ArrayList();

     fo = t.pms_product_ALLSelectlabo();

     foreach (Class entity here pr in fo)
     {
         collection.Add(pr.blabla);
     }

     text_searche.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
     text_searche.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
     text_searche.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
 }
```

and in the first class I need to do that

```
optionDb.AutoComplet(searche, Class entity here);
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the _type_?  What does `pms_product_ALLSelectlabo` return?  Is is not a collection of a single type?

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking about the *type* the simplest was is to make the function [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
 public void AutoComplet<T>(TextEdit text_searche)
 {
     AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

     ArrayList fo = new ArrayList();

     fo = t.pms_product_ALLSelectlabo();

     foreach (T pr in fo.OfType<T>())
     {
         collection.Add(pr.blabla);
     }

     text_searche.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
     text_searche.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
     text_searche.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
 }
```

and call it by supplying the generic parameter:

```
optionDb.AutoComplet<Class entity here>(searche);
```

I would also suggest using strongly-typed collections instead of the archaic `ArrayList`.

Comment: In the logical is true but in the froeach clollection.add(pr.bllala) bllabal is a filed in the database so how can now the field exactly

Comment: Don't forget to specify `where T : BaseTypeWithBlaBla`

Comment: +1 but I must in the fitst method specifier the typeblalalal 
so I need to write more then one mehtod for all class entity

Comment: @del4youdell I'm confused - are you saying that the method won't pull `blabla` each time?  You could pass an expression (`Func<t,string>`) as a parameter and use that in `collection.Add`.  If you need to call methods other than `pms_product_ALLSelectlabo` you could just accept a collection of items rather than pulling it in the method.  Really not very clear what your end goal is.

Comment: the blabla is name of table in dabatabase I use the entity framework 
so I need to pass the the class table exmple Rayon this is a name of table into method this metohd can pass each time a deffrents blabla